# Couldn't syncdb in Django while trying to create table

Tags: python, django, syncdb

This is showing while I am trying to create table using model . I have tried several things but not working .

## Command line

```
(test_env) C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_env\src>python manage.py syncdb 
Operations to perform:   
Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, joins, auth, sessions 

Running migrations:   
No migrations to apply.
```

## My model

```
from django.db import models

class Join(models.Model):
    emai = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Join"
```

## Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'joins',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a table called `joins` in your database? Django not change it if it's already there.

Comment: I just updated the table it showed 'joins' table is updated but I couldn't find that table anywhere . How/where do I find it ? I checked admin as well .

Answer (score 0):

run first

```
python manage.py makemigrations joins
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I just did .. Showing this again :
(test_env) C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_env\src>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(test_env) C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_env\src>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, joins, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

(test_env) C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_env\src>